# How to make CXF SOAP Request to be printed under log file

Tags: cxf

```java
@InInterceptors(interceptors = "org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor"  )
@OutInterceptors(interceptors = "org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor")

public class SKTWeb implements SKTWebService {

// method logic goes here 

}
```

Hi , after adding these two lines inside the CXF Method Implementation .
I could get whip of  SOAP Requestand Response under tomcat server console

see a  instance of SOAP Request Printed under Tomcat console

```
INFO: Inbound Message
----------------------------
ID: 1
Address: /Sktweb-33.0/services/SKTWeb
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Headers: {cache-control=[no-cache], content-type=[text/xml; charset=UTF-8], connection=[keep-alive], host=[local
Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns4:strategy xmlns:ns
```

Could anybody please tell me how can get this inside my Log file (Log4j)

Currently this is my log4j.properties file

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, A1

# A1 is a DailyRollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.file=/Haieeee.log
log4j.appender.A1.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.A1.append=true
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-22d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} - %m%n
```

And also i have META-INF\cxf\org\apache\cxf\Logger  Log4jLogger.class inside the Web Application .
And also i kept

```xml
<cxf:bus>
<cxf:features>
<cxf:logging/>
</cxf:features>
</cxf:bus>
```

Inside the endpoints.xml file

Any help please

Answer (score 2):

A slight bit of confusion it seems. You need your assembled application to have a locatable file `META-INF/cxf/org.apache.cxf.Logger` (yes, those are dots! It's not a .java or .class file) and it should have the contents:

```
org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger
```

I use exactly the above in my code and it works like a charm. (I don't use it with the message logging *feature* though; too much traffic when deployed for my taste…)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want your properties file to be picked by CXF then it use this properties file instead of CXF's.
I am using spring configuration in my CXF application. If you are not using any Spring config then you create a new config and load it on start up using spring context listener, then you can add the below code in your XML file.

```
<bean id="log4jInitialization"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <value>file:fullpath/filename.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

You can also have `classpath:filename.properties` in the `<list> </list>`. The logging implemented in Spring framework will be used to log all the request and response. You can also use the same logging implementation to use in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Always go with interceptors...Add slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar,slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar and commons-logging-1.1.1.jar. Paste the following code in your cxf.xml...

```
<bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" id="loggingInInterceptor" />
    <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" id="logOutInterceptor" />
    <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor" />
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
        <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <ref bean="logOutInterceptor" />
        </cxf:outInterceptors>
    </cxf:bus>
```